# Storing JSON from API which has null values

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to save `null` value in JSON into postgresql. When I use the following code:

```
resume = Resume.create!({
  parsedres: {"Resume":{"xml:lang":"en","xmlns":"http://ns.hrxml.org/2006-02-28","xmlns:vos":"http://noresm.com/hr-xml/2006-02-28","ResumeId":{"IdValue":null}}}
})
```

I get an error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object

The issue is I get API data without "" for null and when I use JSON.parse

```
resume.parsedres = JSON.parse(response.body)
resume.save
```

It throws the

```
JSON::ParserError: 765: unexpected token at '<ParseResumeResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>Ack</Code><SubCode>Authentication/SubCode><Message>AccountID.</Message><CreditsRemaining>100</CreditsRemaining></ParseResumeResponse>'
```

Why does JSON.parse not interpret `null`?

Comment: The JSON parser error looks like you're trying to parse an XML response. I would try inspecting the response body to see verify if it's actually JSON (maybe you need to include a header in the request to get back JSON content).

Comment: Thanks, I have requested JSON in my API call.                                 resume = Resume.new
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: :post,
    url: 'http://API example',
    payload: params,
    **headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}**
    )

Comment: You may want to include 'Accept' => 'application/json' in the headers as well. If that doesn't work, it may be that the API doesn't support JSON, only XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you provided, the `parsedres` is not JSON but a Ruby [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) literal. Since the literal is Ruby code, you'd need to use Ruby's `nil` keyword instead of `null`:

```
resume = Resume.create!({
  parsedres: {"Resume":{"xml:lang":"en","xmlns":"http://ns.hrxml.org/2006-02-28","xmlns:vos":"http://noresm.com/hr-xml/2006-02-28","ResumeId":{"IdValue":nil}}}
})
```

If you received a JSON string from the API, you should be able to parse it using the code you listed above:

```
require 'json'

resume = Resume.create!({
  parsedres: JSON.parse('{"Resume":{"xml:lang":"en","xmlns":"http://ns.hrxml.org/2006-02-28","xmlns:vos":"http://noresm.com/hr-xml/2006-02-28","ResumeId":{"IdValue":null}}}')
})
```

Based on the exception being thrown, it looks like the `response.body` is XML data, not JSON.

Comment: Thanks! 'Accept' => 'application/json' in the headers did the trick!